# Re-directing linked tables

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, dao

I am having what I believe to be a syntax issue with the third line of code below where I am trying to source a table located in a back-end database in a directory differing than the front end. Run time error is 3055 - file not valid

```vb
Function linkToUnc()

Dim cdb As DAO.Database
Set cdb = CurrentDb

cdb.TableDefs("tblTest01").Connect = ";DATABASE=" & CurrentProject.Path & "\LinkedTablesBE2.accdb"
cdb.TableDefs("tblTest01").RefreshLink

cdb.TableDefs("tblTest02").Connect = ";DATABASE=" & CurrentProject.Path & "\LinkedTablesBE2.accdb"
cdb.TableDefs("tblTest02").RefreshLink

cdb.TableDefs("tblTest03").Connect = ";DATABASE=" & CurrentProject.Path & "C:\Users\Andrea LENTI\DocumentsLinkedTablesBE2.accdb"
cdb.TableDefs("tblTest03").RefreshLink

Set cdb = Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using an absolute path in the middle of a relative path. I bet you want `";DATABASE=" & "C:\Users\Andrea LENTI\DocumentsLinkedTablesBE2.accdb"`

A technique to avoid errors like this when constructing string variables (expecially in constructing SQL) is to create a string variable to hold the constuction and then examine the results:

```vb
Dim strPath As String
'Incorrect assignment
strPath = ";DATABASE=" & CurrentProject.Path & "C:\Users\Andrea LENTI\DocumentsLinkedTablesBE2.accdb"
Debug.Print strPath 'Displays result of assignment in immediate window
cdb.TableDefs("tblTest03").Connect = strPath
```

Comment: I agree with your solution, though `"You are and absolute path in the middle of a relative path"` not really sure what you meant there Haha.